# Keras LSTM batch input shape

Tags: keras, lstm

Hello I can not seem to figure out the relationship between the reshapping of X,Y with the batch input shape of Keras when dealing with a LSTM.

current database is a 84119,190 pandas dataframe i am bringing in.  from there break out to X and Y.  so features is 189.  If you could point out where i am wrong as it relates to the (sequence, timestep, dimensions) it would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM    

# load dataset
training_data_df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/####/python_folders/stock_folder/XYstore/Big_data22.csv")


X = training_data_df.drop('Change Month End Stock Price', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['Change Month End Stock Price']].values


data_dim = 189
timesteps = 4
numberofSequence = 1

X=X.reshape(numberofSequence,timesteps,data_dim)
Y=Y.reshape(numberofSequence,timesteps, 1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True,batch_input_shape=(timesteps,data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(1,return_sequences=False, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,Y,epochs=100)
```

## Edit to fix issue

thanks to the help below.  Both helped me think through the problem.  still have some work to do to really understand it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM




training_data_df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/TurnerJ/python_folders/stock_folder/XYstore/Big_data22.csv")

training_data_df.replace(np.nan,value=0,inplace=True)
training_data_df.replace(np.inf,value=0,inplace=True)
training_data_df = training_data_df.loc[279:,:]
X = training_data_df.drop('Change Month End Stock Price', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['Change Month End Stock Price']].values


data_dim = 189
timesteps = 1
numberofSequence = 83840

X=X.reshape(numberofSequence,timesteps,data_dim)
Y=Y.reshape(numberofSequence,timesteps, 1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True,batch_input_shape=(32,timesteps,data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(1,return_sequences=True, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X,Y,epochs=100)
```

Comment: What is a nature of your data? Does your data consist of 84419 sequences of length 189 or it's a single sequence with 189 features and length of 85K. What is the main purpose of your model?

Comment: please tell me if i am wrong but i think it is 189 sequences with 84119 lengths.  So column headers are things like net income, cash flow per share, book value per share... for 189 features.  the rows are dates such as feb 2010. this goes back to 84119 values.

Comment: And you want to divide them into subsequences of length 4, am I right?

Comment: So do you rather have 189 sequences or one sequence with 189 features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `batch_input_shape` needs the size of the batch: `(numberofSequence,timesteps,data_dim)`
- `input_shape` needs only the shape of a sample: `(timesteps,data_dim)`.

Now, there is a problem.... 84199 is not a multiple of 4, how can we expect to reshape it in steps of 4?

There may also be other issues, such as:

- If you have one single long sequence, why divide it in steps?
- If you intend to use a sliding window case, you need to prepare your data as this: Sample 1 = [step1,step2,step3,step4]; Sample 2 = [step2,step3,step4,step5]; and so on. This will imply in `numberofSquence > 1` (something near the 90000)
- If you intend to have a single sequence divided because of memory/performance issues, you should be using `stateful=True` and call `model.reset_states()` at the beginning of every epoch.